# how to load pcd file in pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm

I use python-pcl and want to load a pcd file.
My code is :

```
cloud_blob = pcl.load('./Downloads/table_scene_lms400.pcd')
```

this code works fine in shell, but in `Pycharm` always have error:

```
[pcl::PCDReader::readHeader] Could not find file './Downloads/table_scene_lms400.pcd'
```

I don't know why.

Comment: Check if my answer worked, if not, try giving an absolute file i.e. removing the "./" from the start with the actual path.

Comment: thanks for Reply , but it doesn't work,

Comment: Check full path the file by `pwd` command in the destination and check the capital words ...

Answer (score 1):

First install pypcd

`pip install pypcd`

Then run:

```
import pypcd
pc = pypcd.PointCloud.from_path('table_scene_lms400.pcd')
```

Reference taken from [here](https://pypi.org/project/pypcd/)

Comment: AttributeError: module 'pypcd' has no attribute 'PointCloud'